# Group By two Date columns and Sum Two Columns in a join

Tags: sql-server

I want to group my data by two dates (`dateDu` and `DateAu`)and sum two columns (`Debit` and `Credit`)from different tables join.

```
select   
    DateDu,
    DateAu,
    Det.Debit, 
    Det.Credit,
    Det.Debit - Det.Credit as 'Solde'
from AffectationAbonnement Aff
    join DetailAbonnements Det 
        on Aff.Abonnement_Id = Det.Abonnements_Id
where Abonnement_Id= 8
```

[image]

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: How i can do that

Comment: just i want group by tow date dateDu and DateAu ana sum tow columns DEbit,Credit

Comment: @hamzaBenlaama Please check my answer

Comment: yes is correct think you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you need is a query like below

```
select   
    DateDu,
    DateAu,
    'Solde'=SUM(Det.Debit) - SUM(Det.Credit) 
from AffectationAbonnement Aff
    join DetailAbonnements Det 
        on Aff.Abonnement_Id = Det.Abonnements_Id
where Abonnement_Id= 8
group by DateDu, DateAu
```

Comment: @hamzaBenlaama Please accept my reply as correct answer as it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Comment: i Accepte to ansower